# Wordpress: include content of one page in another

Tags: php, wordpress

How do I include the page content of one or more page in another page?

ex. I have ***pageA***, ***pageB*** and ***pageC*** and I want to include the contents of these pages in ***pageX***

is there a wordpress function that loads the post of a specified page/post?
like show_post("pageA")??

Comment: The easiest way might be [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-pages/)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is not a `show_post()` function per se in WordPress core but it is extremely easy to write:

```
function show_post($path) {
  $post = get_page_by_path($path);
  $content = apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content);
  echo $content;
}
```

Note that this would be called with the page's path, i.e.:

```
<?php show_post('about');  // Shows the content of the "About" page. ?>
<?php show_post('products/widget1');  // Shows content of the "Products > Widget" page. ?>
```

Of course I probably wouldn't name a function as generically as `show_post()` in case WordPress core adds a same-named function in the future. Your choice though.

Also, and no slight meant to *@kevtrout* because I know he is very good, consider posting your WordPress questions on StackOverflow's sister site [**WordPress Answers**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com) in the future. There's a much higher percentage of WordPress enthusiasts answering questions over there.

Comment: @dany - You are welcome. Come on over to WordPress Answers next time and you'll see more like this... :)

Comment: is there any way to do this with individual items?

Comment: @sat - Best to [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) where you can specify all the details of your use-case.

Comment: Is it possible to add more parameters to this function so that it can display the featured image in another place? i.e. show_post('featured_image')  ?

Answer (score 3):

I found [this answer](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/showing-one-pages-content-on-another-page#post-4009184) posted on the Wordpress forums. You add a little code to functions.php and then just use a shortcode whenever you like.

```
function get_post_page_content( $atts ) {
        extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'id' => null,
            'title' => false,
        ), $atts ) );

        $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id='.$id );
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
                if($title == true){
                the_title();
                }
                the_content();
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
    add_shortcode( 'my_content', 'get_post_page_content' );
```

For the shortcode,

```
[my_content id="Enter your page id number" title=Set this to true if you want to show title /]
```

Comment: Shortcode must return, not echo.
Use return with get_the_title, get_the_content functions.

Answer (score 2):

Pages are just posts, with a post_type of 'page' in the database.  You can show the content of multiple pages on another page by writing a post query in your pageX template that gets the posts you specify and output them in a Loop.

There are three ways to get post content from the database:

1. [get_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts)
2. [query_posts](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts)
3. [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/WP_Query)

These links all point to the WordPress Codex.  Get_posts and query_posts have an argument available, 'page_id', where you can specify the id of the page you'd like to retrieve and display.

Answer (score 2):

You could install a Plugin ["Improved Include Page"](https://wordpress.org/plugins/improved-include-page/). Once installed, you create page X and enter:

```
[include-page id="123"]
[include-page id="124"]
[include-page id="125"]
```

where these are the ID's of pages A, B and C respectively

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php query_posts('p=43');

global $more;
//set $more to 0 in order to only get the first part of the post
$more = 0; 

    // the Loop
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 

     // the content of the post ?>
    the_title();
    the_content(); 

    endwhile; ?>
```

This is obviously a portion of the post, I got the detail from the wordpress codex.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting... I looked around for how to embed Wordpress content *elsewhere* (as in, on another website), and found some things...

- www . shooflydesign.org/buzz/past/embedding_wordpress . html

  - Shows how to embed Wordpress content in another site with a php script; maybe just use the same thing to embed Wordpress into itself?
- www . corvidworks . com/articles/wordpress-content-on-other-pages

  - Similar concept; embed Wordpress on another page; just try to use that tool in a new WP post
- feeds themselves

  - My searching pulled up some suggestions to just use a feed to your own blog to embed into a post. There's nothing preventing that. You might want it automated and so restructuring the feed to look right might be problematic, but it's worth a shot depending on what you want to do.

Hope those are quasi-helpful. While they all are solutions for getting your WP content on some place *other* than WP... they might work for your given question and allow you to display A, B, and C on X.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Wordpress function to display the content of a particular page inside another using query_posts() it is:

```
<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&post_id=134"); the_post(); ?>
```

You set the number of pages to be displayed to 1, post type is page instead of post and the page id

Comment: query_posts won't allow a call of 'post_id', but instead must use 'p'. The code as-is will work, but it will instead return the most recently created page. The fixed code below will return the 'post_id' that is specified.   
`<?php query_posts("posts_per_page=1&post_type=page&p=134"); the_post(); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

Kit Johnson's wordpress forum solution with creating a shortcode works, but adds the inserted page in the top of the new page, not where the shortcode was added. Close though, and may work for other people.

from the wordpress post, I pieced together this which inserts the page where the shortcode is put:

```
function get_post_page_content( $atts ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'id' => null,
        'title' => false,
    ), $atts ) );
    $output = "";       

    $the_query = new WP_Query( 'page_id='.$id );
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
            if($title == true){
            $output .= get_the_title();
            }
            $output .= get_the_content();
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $output;

}
```

Then, the shortcode bit works as expected. If you don't want the title, title=false does not work, you need to leave title off entirely.