# Include a php file in a Wordpress page.

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I would like to include a php file, which is stored in my wp-includes folder, that does a cURL call to a remote server. Now that script is working well and everything.

I would like it to load when one of Wordpress pages gets opened. I have tried the following.

```
<?php include 'wp-includes/myfilename.php'; ?>
```

but nothing seems to be loaded. I can visit the url for the specific php file and it make the cURL call perfectly. How can I include this page in my wordpress?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4090698/wordpress-include-content-of-one-page-in-another

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use get_home_path() [(@codex)](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path)

```
<?php include get_home_path . 'wp-includes/myfilename.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @nozifel but that didn't quite load the php page or rather the cURL script. I tried adding the full path to the root as suggested in the codex too.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of `wp_remote_get` function:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get

From the docs:

> Retrieve the raw response from the HTTP request using the GET method.
>   Results include HTTP headers and content.

Example:

```
<?php
function get_remote_file_33199022(){
    wp_remote_get(
      'http://remote-url.com/file.php',
      array(
         'blocking' => false,
         'httpversion' => '1.1'
      )
    );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have already taken care of the curl http request and I have the data received structured in the format I want. Tbh, all I need to do is a simple include on my page but Wordpress is quite complicated.

Comment: What does the function do when instead of the remote url, you put in the local file that you want to include?

Comment: it gets the data and writes that into a json file, which I in turn use it to visualize the data.